Simple Python question: How to Image3D of Mathematica can be done in Python?
In Mathematica,
id = Image3DSlices["ImageData"]

(Sorry the "ImageData" is the Yellow Image of the First Example in the following URl, but I couldn't attach here.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3DSlices.html.en
)
Then just
Image3D[id]    

gives us the 3D image data from sliced images. The 3D image can be rotated freely by drag. But how can I do "Image3D" of sliced images with python?
If someone knows how to do, please help me!!

You can use PyVista:


def load_slices(folder_path):
    """
    Load slices from a folder and stack them into a 3D numpy array.
    """
    slices = []
    for file_name in sorted(os.listdir(folder_path)):
        if file_name.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.tif')):
            image = Image.open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name))
            slices.append(np.array(image))
    # Stack into a 3D array
    volume = np.stack(slices, axis=0)
    return volume

def visualize_3d(volume):
    """
    Visualize the 3D volume using PyVista.
    """
    # Convert the volume to a pyvista UniformGrid
    grid = pv.UniformGrid()
    grid.dimensions = volume.shape
    grid.point_data["values"] = volume.flatten(order="F")
    # Visualize the volume
    plotter = pv.Plotter()
    plotter.add_volume(grid, opacity="sigmoid", cmap="viridis")
    plotter.show()

# Specify the folder containing image slices
folder_path = "path_to_folder"

# Load and visualize
volume_data = load_slices(folder_path)
visualize_3d(volume_data)



Oh, Thank you so much for your great help! Actually, I did the code above, and it seemed that there was no error until volume_data = load_slices(folder_path). However, in the last line, the Error says                                                                "feature = inspect.getattr_static(sys.modules['pyvista.plotting'], name),
except AttributeError:
--->      raise AttributeError(f"module 'pyvista' has no attribute '{name}'") from None,
return feature
AttributeError: module 'pyvista' has no attribute 'UniformGrid'"

I'm a beginner of python and I don' t know what to do now...

According to another question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77696805/pyvista-3d-visualization-issue             I tried "pip install pyvista==0.42.3" in the command line. Then I changed your code  from "grid = pv.UniformGrid()" to  "grid = pv.ImageData()" .                              Then I could get the 3D Image!!! Thank you SO MUCH!!

Glad to hear that, also

Thank you VERY MUCH!!
